# Are there features in Susy that need Compass?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy

The [Susy documentation](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/install/) says:

> The only requirement is Sass, but Susy was built to be part of the Compass ecosystem, and we recommend pairing with tools like Breakpoint and Vertical Rhythms.

Of course if you want to use the recommended Vertical Rhythms, which is part of Compass, you're dependent on Compass.

But other than using the functions/mixins Compass provides, are there any reasons why I would want to use Compass with Susy? Are there parts of Susy that only work, or work better, when Compass is available?

For example, in the file [_breakpoint-plugin.scss](https://github.com/ericam/susy/blob/8f2ec0c1161f71762e8f5bf17d7a79172ad63902/sass/susy/language/susy/_breakpoint-plugin.scss) you see that Susy actively checks if the Breakpoint Plugin is available, and changes its behavior accordingly. I want to know if there are similar optional dependencies on Compass built in.

*PS, In reaction to the close vote:*
I do not mean to ask for opinions. I want to know if there are features in the Susy codebase that do not work (or not as well) when Compass is not available. I will update the title to make that more clear. Please let me know if you see more ways to improve the question.

Comment: I would love to read some comments by the close-voters, explaining why this question would be opinion-based. Really, this is all about understanding how the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [custom support docs](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/settings/#custom-support) for all our integrations. Basically: we'll use Compass prefixing, clearfix, vertical rhythms, and rem fallback if you ask for them.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] are there any reasons why I would want to use Compass with Susy?

Yes, compass has some mixins and functions that aren't available in Susy. For example: [sticky footer](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/layout/sticky_footer/).

> Are there parts of Susy that only work, or work better, when Compass is available?

As far as I'm concerned it doesn't. If you read it correctly you will see this:

> The ***only*** requirement is ***Sass***, but Susy was built ***to be part
>   of*** the ***Compass ecosystem***, and we ***recommend*** pairing with
>   tools like Breakpoint and Vertical Rhythms.

This is for Susy 2, but for 1 however:

> Compass ***is still required*** for the Susy One syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I did read that correctly, but the added emphasis does not answer my question. I am trying to understand what "built to be part of the Compass ecosystem" means exactly.

Comment: I guess that it means: To be used with. It's a recommendation, not a mandatory. The definition of ecosystem: "a system, or a group of interconnected elements, formed by the interaction of a community of organisms with their environment." - THAT simple.

Comment: Sure, it means that it's recommended, not mandatory. We both understand the words. But I'm trying to understand *why* it's recommended. For instance, see the file [_breakpoint-plugin.scss](https://github.com/ericam/susy/blob/8f2ec0c1161f71762e8f5bf17d7a79172ad63902/sass/susy/language/susy/_breakpoint-plugin.scss): Susy actively checks if the Breakpoint Plugin is available and changes its behavior accordingly. There is a significant difference between "recommended because I like what it does" and "recommended because it changes how Susy works".

Comment: Check the [custom support docs](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/settings/#custom-support) for all our integrations. Basically: we'll use Compass prefixing, clearfix, vertical rhythms, and `rem` fallback if you ask for them.

Comment: Thank you, @E.MiriamSuzanne. That comment should be the accepted answer if you ask me.